# How to get all input textbox value from table using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have one table. In that table I have 10 rows and each row has 3 columns.
Inside every `td` we have a `textbox`.

How can I retrive all `textbox` values from the `td` table using `jQuery`?

Here is my table:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click',"#submitButton",function(){
    $('#tableId').find('input[type=text]').each(function() {
       console.log(this.value)
    });
  });
});
```